# Mac Post Events to specific background windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, events

I am trying to create an accessibility app that will type in multiple windows at once, neither of which are owned by my app. For instance, let's say you have two Microsoft word documents open. When you hit a keystroke I want the command to go to both windows.

I have tried using Quartz events services, but it looks like it will only allow you to post to events either on a global or process level. But if two windows are running for the same process, how do I post to a specific window?

There's also the issue of the person typing in one window, while the content is being copied to the next.

Is it possible to post to a single window?

PS I know it's [possible to do this in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried using NSNotificationCenter? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You're talking about interfering with the event/input dispatch of another process. That doesn't sound like a great idea, and I doubt there's going to be any built-in, system facility for that. It would be possible using some kind of code injection, however.

Comment: I know in Windows, you can post events like mouse clicks and keyboard presses to specific windows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS X includes a few tools which may be helpful. You should look into the Accessibility framework, Automator actions, and AppleScript. You should also be aware of application-specific solutions; in the case of Word, for example, you might look at VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). All of these tools provide ways that you can modify the content of other applications. Unfortunately, the level of support for each one varies from one application to another, and the way they're used also varies. So, it's unlikely that you'll find a single solution that works for all applications.

It's unlikely that you'll find a way to insert events directly into another process's event queue. That'd be a huge security hole, for one thing. Even if you could do that, you really wouldn't be able to target specific windows with your events. Mac applications use a responder chain that sends keystrokes to the "first responder", usually a component of the active window.